# Ansible - Does copy support shell * expansion

Tags: file, copy, jinja2, ansible

Ansible 1.9.2 / newer.

Playbook:

```
# Push Performance tests artifact zip file on remote jmeter machine
- name: Push Performance tests artifact zip file on remote jmeter machine
  copy: src="performance-tests-*.zip"  dest={{ common_download_dir }}
```

It errors out:

```
19:32:08 TASK: [perf_tests | Push Performance tests artifact zip file on remote jmeter machine] *** 
19:32:08 fatal: [jmeter01.server.in.vcloud] => input file not found at /home/service/workspace/run-project-performance-tests/build/artifacts/roles/perf_tests/files/performance-tests-*.zip or /home/service/workspace/run-project-performance-tests/build/artifacts/performance-tests-*.zip
19:32:08 
19:32:08 FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

I checked on the source machine (where I'm running ansible), the workspace have valid file: performance-tests-0.0.8-20151001.232123-11.zip

Doesn't ansible support shell expansion i.e. * in src= parameter (into all files) during it's copying operation like `copy: src="somePath/*.zip" dest="somePathOnRemoteMachine"`?

All of the examples on Ansible site: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/copy_module.html shows.. only one file for **src=...** parameter.

**PS**: I'm not using the validate paramter in copy module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_loops.html#looping-over-fileglobs with_fileglob matches all files in a single directory, non-recursively, that match a pattern. It can be used like this::

```
# copy each file over that matches the given pattern
- copy: src={{ item }} dest=/etc/fooapp/ owner=root mode=600
  with_fileglob:
    - /playbooks/files/fooapp/*
```

Comment: Sounds promising, I'll try that and update back. Thanks.

Comment: It worked (I used xxxx-*.zip) for me. I saw a blog which said if it's just * then it might not work but *.* worked.

Comment: HOW would I do the same (shell expansion) if I'm using "unarchive" instead of "copy" module?

Comment: You can use `with_fileglob` with any module.

Answer (score 1):

It does not.

I guess the easiest way would be to use the [shell](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/shell_module.html) module, and issue the `cp` command directly.

Comment: I expected that. It's really strange that why Ansible can't expand shell (seems like due to Jinja2 ?). Other thing I noticed it doesn't let me use a variable for ex: {{ var_{{ giga }}_value }} .. where giga can be "new" or "old" and var_new_value is "NEW" and var_old_value is "OLD", then using {{ var_{{ giga }}_value }} I can't evaluate it to either of those 2 new_xxx_value variable depending upon what's set in variable giga.

Comment: @ArunSangal It being unable to expand the shell has nothing to do with jinja2.  It's because it's not using the shell to evaluate the arguments.

Comment: @ArunSangal Also, it's a bit roundabout, but you can access variables "programmatically" to accomplish what you are looking for in the example in your comment: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-access-a-variable-name-programmatically